# Updating mongodb table through python and pyramid framework

Tags: python, json, updates, pyramid

Good day all. I was wondering if you could help me with a problem. See I need to do an update of a value in a mongodb database using python in a pyramid framework. The front end / jinja2 works. It's just that the back end exploded. The whole logic behind this is to keep data 1 updated whilst also saving succeeding data.

Please help, thanks alot.

[This is a sample of my default.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY3QZ.jpg)

[This is a sample of my models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdj77.jpg)

[This is a sample of my error whenever i do a pserve production.ini --reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8j22.jpg)

Comment: Hi, please instead of pasting images it would be nice if you could paste your real code here

Comment: Your `waterNow1` method has 3 separate unconditional return statements. I'm not sure how that's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is referring to an indentation problem in `default.py` line 76.